# binary_search with Pointers

Tags: c++

i want to  implement binary_search with  pointers

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int binary_p(int x[],int size,int target){
    int *p=&x[0];
    int *q=&x[size];

    while(p<q){
               int mid=(p+q)>>2;
               if (target==x[*mid]) return 1;
               else if(target<x[*mid])  q=mid-1;
               else p=mid+1;





               }   
    return -1;


}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x[]={2,4,6,7,9,10,12};
    int size=sizeof(x)/sizeof(int);
    int target=9;
    cout<<binary_p(x,size,target)<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

but here is error list

```
  prog.cpp: In function ‘int binary_p(int*, int, int)’:
prog.cpp:10: error: invalid operands of types ‘int*’ and ‘int*’ to binary ‘operator+’
prog.cpp:11: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
prog.cpp:12: error: invalid operands of types ‘int*’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator*’
prog.cpp:12: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’
prog.cpp:13: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
prog.cpp:30: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int system(const char*)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
```

please could anybody  give me advise

Comment: You can't do `>>2` (or `/4` for that matter) on pointers. Pointer arithmetic only allows addition and subtraction. Why not work with indices instead?

Comment: system executes an external command... is that what you really want?

Comment: Recursive call to `binary_p` missing?

Comment: @another.anon.coward: Binary search does not have to be implemented recursively, a loop will do just fine.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: Thanks! Duly Noted ... its been a while but that should not have been a reason for me to overlook the logic implemented here :\

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here is the working code.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int binary_p(int x[],int size,int target){
    int *p = &x[0];
    int *q = &x[size - 1 ];

    while( *p < *q ){
        int mid = (*p + *q) >> 2;
        if (target == x[mid]) 
            return 1;
        else if (target < x[mid])  
            *q = mid - 1;
        else 
            *p = mid + 1;
    }   
    return -1;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x[] = {2,4,6,7,9,10,12};
    int size = sizeof(x) / sizeof(int);
    int target = 9;
    cout << binary_p(x,size,target) << endl;
    //system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: one question @Avinash  ,we are  dividing (*p+*q) by 4?because sizeof(int) is 4 or why?thanks for help

Comment: Does this really work?  Try it on `int x[] = { 1000, 2000, 100000 };` or something similar.  The calculation of `mid` is completely wrong; you can't use the values in the original array to create an index into the array, since they are unrelated.

Answer (score 4):

You can't add (or shift, or divide) two pointers, but subtracting them
gives an integral type (which you can add and divide), so you can write
something like:

```
int* mid = p + (q - p) / 2;
```

to obtain a pointer to the middle point.

Comment: With indexes, this approach also prevents overflows, so it should be preferred anyway.

Comment: @BjörnPollex Or you could use an unsigned type for indexing, and count on the modulo arithmetic giving you the correct value in the end.  (Or you're using 64 bit integers, and you know your array can't be that big:-).)  But in general, yes.  This is the only correct way to determine the mid-point.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this:

```
  int mid=(p+q)>>2
```

Adding pointers doesn't have any meaning.  You are thinking of `int*` as `int`, but it might not be so, and C doesn't automatically treat them as such.  You could cast, but then it won't be standard.

You can subtract pointers that are in the same array.  That returns an int.  Also, you can add an int to pointer.

So,

```
  int* mid=p + ((q-p) / 2);
```

would work.  `mid` should be an `int *`, so you need to change the rest of your code to work with that.  You have similar errors elsewhere.  For example, the next line

```
   if (target==x[*mid]) return 1;
```

didn't make sense even if mid was an int (*mid isn't allowed on int), but now mid points right at the element, so you want:

```
   if (target==*mid) return 1;
```

and, so on.

Comment: Because you probably have a bug.  use the debugger to figure out what is going on.  If you want help, you need to post your new code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add pointers. If you *really* insist on doing it the hard way (instead of using indexes), you should use std::distance and std::advance functions.

Comment: You CAN add, subtract pointers. Consider this: int a[5]; int *ptr1, ptr2; ptr1 = a; ptr2 = a[4]; ptr2-ptr1 == 4

Comment: @friendzis: In your example you subtract pointers, but you don't add them. That is not possible.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: 1. it IS possible, though doesn't make sense. 2. It's just not straightforward - you have to explicitly tell the compiler to take integral values of pointers, i.e. in subtraction case it is done implicitly. Subtraction: a-b; addition: (int)a + (int)b

Comment: @friendzis: When you do this you are adding integers, not pointers. If you dereference a pointer that results from such an addition, I am pretty sure you get undefined behavior.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: well, but pointers ARE the very same integers. Their value is integer, that has size of your architecture e.g. 64bits/16Bytes. Pointer type denotes what RESIDES at memory location that has the same value as pointer's value. Therefore when you add pointers you get pretty much defined behavior. `    int arr[2] = {1, 2};
    int *ptr1 = arr;
    int *ptr2 = (int *)(1*sizeof(*arr));
    int *ptr3 = (int*)((int)ptr1 + (int)ptr2);
    printf("%d\n", *ptr3); // 2` This is pretty defined behavior. If you take two pointer pointing to actual data in your application, then it will

Comment: point to location that is most probably out of your application's range. and dereferencing that will cause undefined behavior. As I've already stated: pointer addition just makes no logical sense, but you can't say it's completely impossible (: Sorry for split comment

Answer (score 0):

```
while(p<=q){
    int *mid=p+(q-p)/2;
    if (target==*mid) return 1;
    else if(target<*mid)  q=mid-1;
    else p=mid+1;
}   
return -1;
```